# Rails 4 : find or create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have an association between `experience` and `company` where company `has_many :experiences` and experience `belongs_to :company`, Now I want to design this: if a user enters a company name that already exist in the company model it will assign to it but if the user put a company name that doesn't already exist in company model - the company must persist but not be created as a new record (I don't want to use `find_or_create` method and the `find_by` doesn't seem working for this situation)

Edit

this is my Company controller

```
def allcompanies
    @companies = Company.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order("created_at DESC")
  end



  def show
    @company = Company.find_by_slug(params[:id])

    if @company
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end

  end

  def index
    @companies = Company.limit(19).order("id DESC")
  end


  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        flash[:notice] = "Entreprise '#{@company.name}' Crée!"
        format.html { redirect_to @company}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update(company_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Entreprise '#{@company.name}' à été mis à jour"
        format.html { redirect_to @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @company.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to companies_url }
    end
  end



  private


    def set_company
      @company = Company.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    end


    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :company_description, :country, :city, :company_status, :company_size, :company_website, :sector_ids, :job_id, :companylogo)
    end
```

and this is my experience model that actually create a new record for each company

```
    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :company

    validates :company_name, presence: true


  def company_name
    company.try(:name)
  end

  def company_name=(name)
     self.company = Company.find_or_initialize_by(name: name)
  end
```

Comment: > company must persist but not be created as a new record - how is that?

Comment: I don't know that is why i'm asking, and linkedin is already doing that if you put in your experience a company name that doesn't exist in their db this company will not be created

Comment: how do you know it isn't created in their db, did you check? Possibly it just has field named like `public_visible` with `false` for that company.

Comment: that is brilliant idea but how can i know if a company is created via experience to do something like this

Comment: show your current controller action to adjust. I have no idea how do you do this now so can't tell you what to change.

Comment: Actually my controller is a basic controller generated by scaffolding the experience is belongs_to a profile and profile has many experience and accept experience as nested attribute and experience belongs to a company which has many experience

Comment: you can see my company controller and my experience model in my updat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69027/discussion-between-djrs12-and-rustam-a-gasanov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you want some `companies` to be visible and some not.

Then, you can create a corresponding `boolean` field, like `public_visible` and set it to `false` for `companies` you don't know(ie created by application users).

In your controller do something like this:

```
@company = Company.find_by_name(params[:company][:name])
if @company.blank?
  @company = Company.create(params[:company].merge({ public_visible: false }))
end
@company.experiences.create(...)
```

it is just an example, since I don't know your real conditions on companies creation, so you need to adjust it according to your needs.

Comment: Can i do something like this in my experience model   if company.new_record?
  @company = Company.create(params[:company].merge({ public_visible: false }))
end

Comment: @djrs12 if it fits your needs - why not? You didn't show your models/controllers, so I can't tell exact way, just _how_ to do this - implementation is up to you.

Comment: I have tried this but I'm getting this error uninitialized constant Profile::Experience